# Do I have to collect everything?

Tags: poochy-and-yoshis-woolly-world

In most Yoshi games, if you collect all of the stars/coins/flowers each level in a world, this unlocks a special level.

Is this the same for this game, except with hearts/stamps/flowers? Does collecting all of each thing unlock another level? Or do I only have to collect some things?

(I know this game makes some things easier with Mellow Mode, so I wasn't sure if this would be affected, or if it is even something that happens in this game.)

Answer (score 1):

First, i've played the Wii U version of Yoshi's Wooly World and as far as i know, the poochy version / DS version is mostly the same. So my answer is based on the WiiU version, but poochy owners feel free to correct me.

There are a three sets of collectibles each level that unlock the following things:

- Flowers: Collecting all flowers in all levels of a world unlocks a special bonus level that is harder than most levels present in the game. Collecting all flowers in the bonus levels unlocks a 'super' bonus level that is very long (and fun)
- Wool: Collecting all 5 wool bundles in a level unlocks a new color/pattern for yoshi, which you can alter on the main island
- Stamps: Colleting all 20 stamps in a level unlocks stamps that you can use in the MiiVerse. They have no effect on the game (other than 100% completion)

There is also an indicator for having all collectibles and 20/20 hearts at the end of the level, which is a (purely cosmetic) gold star. It makes you a bit cooler ofcourse :)

Sources: Own 100% playthrough, [IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/yoshis-wooly-world/Collectibles), [Prima Games](https://www.primagames.com/games/yoshis-woolly-world/tips/yoshis-woolly-world-tips-and-tricks-badges-smiley-flowers-mellow-mode)